# Conducting Two-Way PERMANOVA in R using adonis in vegan package, and post-hoc tests

Tags: r, vegan, posthoc, manova

Because the code is rather intense in R I instead did a Two-Way PERMANOVA in PAST (Palaeontological Statistical Software), however, I need to do Post-Hoc tests which I can't seem to do in PAST, so I reverted back to R. The results I get in R are significantly different from those in PAST, and I'm not sure if I'm coding it wrong, or whether PAST is simply unreliable?

Here is a link to a subsample of my [data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/48247ea4573e42bd546f7f625ff1ce7e/CSS.csv)

And the code I used:

```
options(scipen=999)
library(vegan)
attach(data)

#1. Standardize data to get them on the same scale and add to dataset
N1<-scale(data$nutr1)
N2<-scale(data$nutr2)
N3<-scale(data$nut3)

data<-cbind(data,N1)
data<-cbind(data,N2)
data<-cbind(data,N3)

DV<-cbind(data$N1,data$N2,data$N3)
IV<-cbind(data$sample,data$treatment)

#2. Permutational Multivariate Analysis of Variance (PERMANOVA)
#IV1
adonis(formula=DV~data$sample,permutations=9999,method="euclidean")
#IV2
adonis(formula=DV~data$treatment,permutations=9999,method="euclidean")
#IV interaction
adonis(formula=DV~IV,permutations=9999,method="euclidean")
```

The p-value for IV1 = 0.0001 in PAST, but = 0.4485 in R

The p-value for IV2 = 0.0001 in PAST, but = 0.7384 in R

The p-value for the interaction between IV1 and IV2 = 0.0466 in PAST, but = 0.2275 in R

I realize the data is incomplete which adds to the discrepancy in this example, however even when I use the full data set IV1 is still insignificant, and although IV2 and the interaction are then significant the p-values are different compared to those I got in PAST.

Am I doing something wrong in my code? Am I performing a Two-Way PERMANOVA correctly in R?
Also, does anyone have any links to some code for a pairwise two-sided multiple comparison analysis for Post Hoc analysis?

P.S. I don't understand the technical jargon too well, so be gentle with me please :)